# converting string (hex) to decimal results in exception

Tags: c#, exception, character-encoding, hex

My question seems simple, but I have googled for a couple of hours without result.
I have to use a string (hex format) and convert to integer. (the string is returned from a commercial library).

if I do,

```
string stringInHex = getThevaluefromthelibrary(); //psuedo
```

and print stringInHex using

```
stringInHex.ToString()
```

I can see 0x00

but if I try to convert it to a int, see below:

```
int myInt = int.Parse(stringInHex , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception errorSystem.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
```

I think the string which is returned from the library that I am using is encoded weird in some how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The string can not contain the **0x** prefix. Simply passing the value **00** would achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah, and I was a good 2 mins slower, but didn't get the answers loaded until after mine.

Comment: Yes guys, the answer is right. (and I am going to kill myself now ;) Don´t know how I could have forgot this

Comment: TBH, I've hit this more than once. Keep thinking it should work as you were trying.

Answer (score 2):

```
int myInt = int.Parse(stringInHex.Substring(2) , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

You aren't allowed to include the leading "0x", so pass what follows to `int.Parse` instead.